# Remove a File using separate function (Dropzone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a `cancel` button on Click of which the uploaded file should be removed. 
My HTML looks like this

```
<div reqdropzone="reqDropzoneConfig">
 <form id="requisitionupload" class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="">
  <div class="dz-default dz-message">
   <span style="display: none;"></span>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

in my `JS`.

```
$scope.cancel = function() {
 $(function(){
   var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#requisitionupload");
   myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file){
    file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
     myDropzone.removeFile(file);
    });
   })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You chain two events, first "addedfile" who get file parameter and after click on preview element of this file variable. This second event will not always know file.

Easy way is to use Dropzone options 'addRemoveLinks:true'.

Or a custom solution can be creating a temporary variable in first event to store 'file' and in second event (click) you refer to this temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do as @Camille said. Since you are tagged with `angularjs` i would encourage you to use [ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone) It makes easy to do things and gives you so much flexibility to handle these kind of things.